# How can I reduce noise from pushrods in an assembly without using grease/oil?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, applied-mechanics, friction, noise

I have an assembly which consists of a row of vertically-oriented nylon pushrods (each 5/16" in diameter, colored green in the attached pictures), and two black pieces of laser cut delrin separated by a clear piece of acrylic.

Pictures at: https://imgur.com/a/gd2vfY4

The two 1/16" thick black delrin pieces have a row of holes slightly bigger than the pushrods so that the rods can slide up and down. The clear acrylic has a row of holes in the same places but with larger diameters so that the pushrods never touch the acrylic.

It works, but it's a little noisy when the pushrods are moved. How can I reduce the noise without adding a ton of complexity to the part?

Comment: What sort of noise? Clacking due to excessive play? Rubbing noise due to sliding contact?

Comment: There's very little play. It's a rubbing noise due to sliding contact.

Comment: are the pushrods an ideal solution to whatever you are building?

Comment: don't use delrin and acrylic?  like use some type of low-friction poly?

Comment: @Tiger It would have to be a low-friction poly that can safely be laser-cut. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jsotola They would be ideal if not for the noise.

Comment: Dry Lube (Graphite)?